# How to call object key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

i am developing one project of displaying mobiles like Mobile under 5k and mobile under 10k and mobile under 20k and mobile above 20k
Here i am getting the products but i am unable to show title with amount.
i write code like this

```
const [priceRange, setPriceRange] = useState({
    under5k: 5000,
    under10k: 10000,
    under20k: 20000,
    above20k: 20001,
  });

 {Object.keys(product.productsByPrice).map((key, index) => {
        return (
          <div className="card">
            <div className="cardHeader">
              <div>{slug} Mobiles Under {priceRange[key]}</div>
              <button>View All</button>
            </div>
            <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
              {product.productsByPrice[key].map((product) => (
                <div className="productContainet">
                  <div className="productImageContainer">
                    <img
                      src={generatePublicurl(product.productPictures[0].img)}
                      alt=""
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="productInfo">
                    <div style={{ margin: "5px 0" }}>{product.name}</div>
                    <div>
                      <span>4.3</span> &nbsp;
                      <span>3322</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="productPrice">{product.price}</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
```

when i call like this {slug} Mobiles Under {priceRange[key]} i am not getting the amount.
for ref please find the attached image.
[image]

complete code is like this

ProductListPage.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Layout from "../Components/Layout";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { getProductsBySlug } from "../redux/actions";
import "./style.css";
import { generatePublicurl } from "../urlConfig";
function ProductListPage(props) {
  const { slug } = useParams();
  const product = useSelector((state) => state.product);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [priceRange, setPriceRange] = useState({
    under5k: 5000,
    under10k: 10000,
    under20k: 20000,
    above20k: 20001,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProductsBySlug(slug));
  }, []);
  return (
    <Layout>
      {Object.keys(product.productsByPrice).map((key, index) => {
        return (
          <div className="card">
            <div className="cardHeader">
              <div>
                {slug} Mobiles Under {priceRange[key]}
              </div>
              <button>View All</button>
            </div>
            <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
              {product.productsByPrice[key].map((product) => (
                <div className="productContainet">
                  <div className="productImageContainer">
                    <img
                      src={generatePublicurl(product.productPictures[0].img)}
                      alt=""
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="productInfo">
                    <div style={{ margin: "5px 0" }}>{product.name}</div>
                    <div>
                      <span>4.3</span> &nbsp;
                      <span>3322</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="productPrice">{product.price}</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default ProductListPage;
```

product.action.js

```
import axios from "../../helpers/axios";
import { productConstants } from "./constants";

export const getProductsBySlug = (slug) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const res = await axios.get(`/product/getproducts/${slug}`);
    if (res.status === 200) {
      dispatch({
        type: productConstants.GET_PRODUCTS_BY_SLUG,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    }
  };
};
```

product.reducer.js

```
import { productConstants } from "../actions/constants";

const initialState = {
  products: [],
  productsByPrice: {
    under5K: [],
    under10k: [],
    under20k: [],
    above20k: [],
  },
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case productConstants.GET_PRODUCTS_BY_SLUG:
      state = {
        ...state,
        products: action.payload.products,
        productsByPrice: {
          ...action.payload.productsByPrice,
        },
      };
      break;
  }
  return state;
};
```

product.model.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    slug: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
    offer: { type: Number },
    productPictures: [
      {
        img: { type: String },
      },
    ],
    reviews: [
      {
        userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
        review: String,
      },
    ],
    category: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Category",
      required: true,
    },
    createdBy: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: true,
    },
    updatedAt: Date,
  },

  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
```

productRoute.js

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const { requireSignin, adminMiddleware } = require("../common-middleware");
const { addProduct, getProductsBySlug } = require("../controller/product");
const multer = require("multer");
const shortid = require("shortid");
const path = require("path");
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, path.join(path.dirname(__dirname), "uploads"));
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, shortid.generate() + "-" + file.originalname);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

router.post(
  "/create",
  requireSignin,
  adminMiddleware,
  upload.array("productPicture"),
  addProduct
);
router.get("/getproducts/:slug", getProductsBySlug);

module.exports = router;
```

productController.js

```
const Product = require("../models/product");
const slugify = require("slugify");
const shortid = require("shortid");
const Category = require("../models/category");

exports.addProduct = async (req, res) => {
  //   res.status(200).json({ file: req.files, body: req.body });

  const { name, price, description, category, createdBy, quantity } = req.body;
  //   let productPictures = [];
  //   if (req.files.lenght > 0) {
  //     productPictures = req.files.map((file) => {
  //       return { img: file.filename };
  //     });
  //   }

  const product = new Product({
    name: name,
    slug: slugify(name),
    price,
    quantity,
    description,
    productPictures: req.files.map((file) => {
      return { img: file.filename };
    }),
    category,
    createdBy: req.user.id,
  });

  await product.save((error, product) => {
    if (error) return res.status(400).json({ error });
    if (product) {
      res.status(201).json({ product, files: req.files });
    }
  });
};

exports.getProductsBySlug = async (req, res) => {
  const { slug } = req.params;
  await Category.findOne({ slug: slug })
    .select("_id")
    .exec(async (error, category) => {
      if (error) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error });
      }
      if (category) {
        await Product.find({ category: category._id }).exec(
          (error, products) => {
            if (error) {
              return res.status(400).json({ error });
            }
            if (products.length > 0) {
              res.status(200).json({
                products,
                productsByPrice: {
                  under5K: products.filter((product) => product.price <= 5000),
                  under10K: products.filter(
                    (product) => product.price > 5000 && product.price <= 10000
                  ),
                  under20K: products.filter(
                    (product) => product.price > 10000 && product.price <= 20000
                  ),
                  above20K: products.filter((product) => product.price > 20000),
                },
              });
            }
          }
        );
      }
      // res.status(200).json({ category });
    });
};
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: *"complete code is like this"* .... If any of that code is unrelated to the  specific problem it should be removed. Too much code makes it hard for others to help isolate your issue. See [mre]

Comment: @ charlietfl complete code is there please see above

Comment: Also we don't know what `product.productsByPrice` looks like. Perhaps the keys are slighly different?

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood. The complete code is far more than what should be posted to show us your specific problem. Be sure to have  good read through [mre]

Comment: @ charlietfl please check now

Comment: That is still a huge amount of code for what sounds like a small problem